# MYSQL SUM function with and inside

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm doing a query to get several counts at once for a left navigation. I'm summing the number of rows that match each condition and passing that number to the DOM for the left navigation, however two of the SUMS are more complicated than the others and are returning 0 even though I know there are rows in the DB that match the expression.

```
$processingcounts = $second->select(DB::raw(' 
        SUM(scheduled_in != "") as processingPreRepairs,
        SUM(in_arrival = 1) as processingNewArrivals, 
        SUM(delivery_complete = 1) as processingDelivered, 
        SUM(supplement = 1) as processingSupplement, 
        SUM(scheduled_in >= '.$start.' and scheduled_in <= '.$end.') as processingCurrentWeek, 
        SUM(scheduled_in >= '.$nextStart.' and scheduled_in <= '.$nextEnd.') as processingNextWeek, 
        SUM(file_location = "SCHEDULED") as processingScheduledList, 
        SUM(file_location = "IN-SHOP") as processingInShop, 
        SUM(file_location = "OFFICE") as processingOffice 
        '))->first();
```

All the other SUMS are returning the correct values, but the two SUMS I call "processingCurrentWeek" and "processingNextWeek" are returing 0, though they should be returning 2 and 3 respectively. My question is can you use SUM like I do below with basically wheres inside of them.

EDIT:

Here is the query output with the dates, when I dump the laravel query.

```
SUM(scheduled_in != "") as processingPreRepairs,
SUM(in_arrival = 1) as processingNewArrivals, 
SUM(delivery_complete = 1) as processingDelivered, 
SUM(supplement = 1) as processingSupplement, 
SUM(scheduled_in >= 2016-06-13 and scheduled_in <= 2016-06-17) as processingCurrentWeek, 
SUM(scheduled_in >= 2016-06-20 and scheduled_in <= 2016-06-24) as processingNextWeek, 
SUM(file_location = "SCHEDULED") as processingScheduledList, 
SUM(file_location = "IN-SHOP") as processingInShop, 
SUM(file_location = "OFFICE") as processingOffice
```

Comment: Yes, you end up just summing the bool results with TRUE being 1, and FALSE being 0. My first suggestion would be to make sure those variables are holding the values you expect (in the format MySQL expects for date|datetime comparison, and that the fields compared are also appropriately typed). Then look into parameterized queries before "little bobby drop tables" gets you.

Comment: Can you post actual query after all variables(`$start`/`$end`) injected? Can you use placeholders here?

Comment: Ok, dates must be wrapped as strings. They interpreted as expressions now: `2016-06-10 = 2000`

Comment: You should definitely consider bound parameters here. It could also end up helping with the type mismatch or missing quotes which is likely the issue here.

Comment: I hope none of the inline variables are coming from user input... that looks scary.

Comment: It was an issue with me not making my dates as strings, thanks for everyones suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates must be wrapped as strings. They interpreted as expressions now: `2016-06-10 = 2000`.

You can to use placeholders:

```
$processingcounts = $second->select(' 
    SUM(scheduled_in != "") as processingPreRepairs,
    SUM(in_arrival = 1) as processingNewArrivals, 
    SUM(delivery_complete = 1) as processingDelivered, 
    SUM(supplement = 1) as processingSupplement, 
    SUM(scheduled_in >= ? and scheduled_in <= ?) as processingCurrentWeek, 
    SUM(scheduled_in >= ? and scheduled_in <= ?) as processingNextWeek, 
    SUM(file_location = "SCHEDULED") as processingScheduledList, 
    SUM(file_location = "IN-SHOP") as processingInShop, 
    SUM(file_location = "OFFICE") as processingOffice 
    ', [$start, $end, $nextStart, $nextEnd])->first();
```

Comment: That was exactly correct, I hadn't even thought of that being the issue. Thanks for your help.